# Would Hadoop help my situation?

Tags: hadoop

I am in the process of creating a survey engine that will store millions of responses to various large surveys.

There are various agencies that will have 10-100 users each.  Each will be able to administer a 3000+ question survey.  There will be multiple agencies as well.

If each agency was to have hundreds of thousands of sessions each with 3000+ responses, I'm thinking that hadoop would be a good candidate to get the sessions and their response data to run various analyses on (aggregations etc).

The sessions, survey questions, and responses are all currently held in a sql database.  I was thinking that I would keep that and put the data in parallel.  So when a new session is taken under an agency, it is then added to the hadoop 'file', such that when the entire dataset is called up it would be included.

Would this implementation work well with hadoop or am I still well within the limits of a relational database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think anyone is going to be able to tell you definitively, yes or no here. I also don't think I fully grasp what your program will be doing from the wording of the question, however, in general, Hadoop Map/Reduce excels at batch processing huge volumes of data. It is not meant to be an interactive (aka real-time) tool. So if your system:

1) Will be running scheduled jobs to analyze survey results, generate trends, summarize data, etc.....then yes, M/R would be a good fit for this.

2) Will allow users to search through surveys by specifying what they are interested in and get reports in real-time based on their input....then no, M/R would probably not be the best tool for this. You might want to take a look at [HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/). I haven't used it yet, but [Hive](http://hive.apache.org/) is a query based tool but I am not sure how "real-time" that can get. Also, [Drill](http://incubator.apache.org/drill/) is an up and coming project that looks promising for interactively querying big data.